# REST API Http Status code for Unconfirmed email but successful login

Tags: web-services, api, rest, http, http-status

I have a use case here, a user registers in a website and has got an account activation link through email. User tries to login without activating his account.

What would be the **Http status code** for the login request, both username and password is correct but he has not yet activated his account from the activation link through email.

Http Status Code: **XXX**

Http Response

```
{ message: "your email address has not been confirmed yet", description: "Please confirm your account from the activation link sent through email" }
```

Comment: I'd say either `403 Forbidden` or `409 Conflict`. Both allow a response entity that contains further information on the error. The difference between these two states in your case is, that a `409` can be used in situation where a user is expected to resolve a problem before resending the request - in your case the user has to click the activation link first. `403` in this case just states that the user has currently no permission to use the target resource.

Comment: On the other side, `409` would assume that the state of the target resource has some issues when actually the unconfirmed user credentials, which are not part of the resource' state, do produce the error. I'd therefore prefer `403` over `409` after rethinking the use-case

Comment: As Roman said, `409` is definitely wrong. I would agree that it's either `403`, but add to that that I think even `401` is appropriate. I would consider this an authentication problem.

Comment: @Evert `401` is wrong in my opinion as it allows resends and would also pop up those "authentication dialogs (again and again) if invoked via a browser. Furthermore, the user credentials are correct though not activated yet. Most basic auth frameworks would return `BAD_CREDENTIALS` in that case which is simply wrong as the credentials are correct

Comment: You might be right in terms of practicality. I won't dispute that it might be more _convenient_ to not use `401`, however, I do stand by the fact that this is an issue related to authentication, so purely looking at the specs `401` is appropriate. Clicking an activation link in an email is a form of authenticating your identity. The user also never mentioned Basic Auth. In OAuth2 the `401` is used for similar things.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, `401 Unauthorized` is the better choice here over `403 Forbidden` because `403` is used to depict that client is authenticated but trying to access the resource which is not permitted to them.

It could be any endpoint.

Howerver, in this case, the confirmation of email is still pending which is related to authentication. Hence, sending `401 Unauthorized` would make more sense to me here.

Although, it's debatable. We can consider this situation middleware in both things. I guess, `401` and `403` both are fine.